# Glob stops too soon when directory has `.js` in it

Tags: node.js, gulp

We are using gulp, which used node-glob to get the following pattern:

```
'App/public/{js,css}/**/*.{js,css}'
```

Unfortunately one of the desired paths is:

```
'App/public/js/Placeholder.js/dist/placeholder.js'
```

but the glob pattern returns simply:

```
'App/public/js/Placeholder.js'
```

resolving too soon. I could write a horrible complex function to handle this case, but it seems like this should be a solved thing. Google has yielded nothing useful so far. Please help keep this code clean.

Comment: In what context are you using this? `gulp.src`? What problems is it causing you?

Comment: `gulp.src` yes, the trouble is its not matching the file, but rather the parent directory.

Comment: I suspect it's not `gulp.src`, but rather whatever you're piping the files into which is failing. If you try something very simple like `gulp.src('App/public/js/**/*.js').pipe(gulp.dest('build'));`, it will probably copy the files as you expect it should.

Comment: @Ben it doesnt't, I get both `'App/public/js/Placeholder.js/dist/placeholder.js'` and `'App/public/js/Placeholder.js'`

Comment: Right, which means that it's not `gulp.src` which is excluding `App/public/js/Placeholder.js/dist/placeholder.js`. You'll need to exclude `App/public/Placeholder.js` with a filter. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gulp-filter` to filter out directories pretty easily:

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.src('App/public/{js,css}/**/*.{js,css}')
  .pipe(filter(function(file) {
    return file.stat.isFile();
  }))
  .pipe(whatever());
```